# How to make push notification without internet

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

me and my colleague are trying to show "push notification" message in mobile device. Colleague is telling that it can´t be done without Google Cloud Messaging but I think - why use any server for that?

We want something like this: [image]

How our application will work is:
- user has app on background
- ajax request is made (request to our server)
- server response is: You have 1 new message
- message is showed in top strip on mobile.

Of course, the message can be showed without internet.. My GF had mobile app "Pou"... when he pooped notification was displayed... Just I dont get it why to use any Google service for that?

Can somebody direct me pls?

Comment: If you don't want to use any internet protocol, you're pretty much limited to using SMS for sending push notifications. There are tons of sites/services for sending such messages. But such recommendations are beyond the scope of StackOverflow (since everyone typically has their own favorite).

Comment: I think you're mixing up "Push notifications" with simple "Notifications". Any app can locally create a notification like the one in your screenshot. Check out this guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: Thank you. I dont wanna make it by SMS or any server.. why do this when app can locally push message? Thank you @Henrique, but is any possibility to do this in AngularJS?

Comment: Not really sure I understand you. But if your push notifications are not coming from a server, then you have to hardcode when notifications should appear. For example, every X days, or if the user doesn't open the app for X days, etc. The point of having it sent from a server is that you have more control over this, as well as being able to actually push 'new' information to the client (E.g. someone mentioned you in a post, you were tagged in a photo, etc...these are things that cannot be hardcoded into an app).

Comment: So it is working like a CRON job and cannot be called instantly? I think @UserX is true. Only problem is - we are using AngularJS with Ionic and Cordova

Answer (score 3):

You should use  [Notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) to show "push notification".

```
private void showNotification() {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)   
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher) 
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setTicker(getString(R.string.notification_ticker_text)) 
        .setContentText(getString(R.string.notification_content_text))
        .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0))
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()) 
        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name)) 
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL); 

    Notification notification = builder.build(); 
    ((NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).notify(0, notification);        
}
```

Comment: As I commented above, we are using Ionic and Cordova, is there any option to not doing it in native Java?

Comment: Sorry, i haven't used Cordova, but [this post](https://manijshrestha.wordpress.com/2012/11/23/implementing-android-status-bar-notification-in-phonegapcordova-app) may be useful.

Comment: check this out https://github.com/evothings/phonegap-estimotebeacons/wiki/Background-notification-guide

Comment: My use-case is if the user hasn't opened the app for 'n' number of days it should display a push notification. But in this case push notification should work even when the app is not running in the background. Does this solution works for that kinda scenario? If not do we have to get this done using Service? Appreciate your ideas

Comment: @channae, you should save a time of last call of activity's onStop method.For this you can use the [ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html).Also, you should periodically check the time of the last application activity. For this use can use the [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html).

Comment: @UserX Can we use this solution even when the app is closed? (when not running in the background). As my understanding JobScheduler should run even when the app is closed in order to cater such requirement. Thanks

Comment: @channae, yes, you can use this solution even when the app is closed.